# I have a pdf from which I have to extract data and show but I am getting this exception, I'm not being able to figure out what is this Exception is?

Tags: java, exception, servlets, itext, pdf-reader

I have this pdf file to extract data from, but the problem is when I'm running this piece of code as a simple java program, it works like a charm but when I tried this code on JSP servlet it gave out this exception and I'm not being able to figure out what this exception is for?
And I'm using iText API to extract texts from PDFs.

**My code snippet:**

```
<%
                String Source = "Resource/text.pdf";

                PdfReader reader;
                try {
                    //java.net.URL SourcePDF = getClass().getResource("RawMaterial/text.pdf");
                    reader = new PdfReader(Source);

                    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);

                    TextExtractionStrategy strategy = null;

                    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) 
                    {
                        strategy = parser.processContent(i,new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
                        System.out.println(strategy.getResultantText());
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            %>
```

**The exception is:**

```
java.io.IOException: Resource/text.pdf not found as file or resource.
    at com.itextpdf.text.io.RandomAccessSourceFactory.createByReadingToMemory(RandomAccessSourceFactory.java:263)
    at com.itextpdf.text.io.RandomAccessSourceFactory.createBestSource(RandomAccessSourceFactory.java:173)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:219)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:207)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:197)
    at org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:120)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It simply says that your program can't find the specified file. See if you are referencing your files correctly, and they are in classpath.

Comment: Hey, @Aakash, I actually added the code snippet, I don't know why it isn't showing up here?

Comment: You should have used code formatting. Never mind, I have edited that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the problem is solved, I just added this one line of code in the beginning, before specifying the path -

```
<% 
    String relativePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    String Source = relativePath +"Resource/text.pdf";
    ...
    ...
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your file is not found as it may have been place in different location when packages as war/jar or whatever you choose. Check your war file you may fint it under /classes/some/package. So in this case read it as a resource with relative path.

Use classloader ...

```
ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream ("your/pkg/Resource/text.pdf");
```

or you can get it as url

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("your/pkg/Resource/text.pdf");
```